# How to convert ts files to avi in OSX

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, avi, video-conversion, mencoder

I have tried both mencoder and ffmpeg. With ffmpeg the sound was fine but there was no picture. With mencoder the video moved at half speed so the length was doubled. How can this be done right?

Answer (score 0):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) can transcode between MPEG_TS and AVI and will run on OS X.